# Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getContext()Landroid/content/Context;):

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, kotlin-context-receivers

//Child class

```
class DialogPermission(myContext : Context) : BaseDialog(myContext) {
    private var mBtnPermission: Button? = null
    private var mOnClickListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener? = null
    override fun setWidthScale(): Float {
        return 0.9f
    }
```

// parent class

```
abstract class BaseDialog(protected var context: Context) :
    Dialog(context, R.style.DialogTransparent) {...
```

// error of parent class

Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getContext()Landroid/content/Context;):

```
public final fun `<get-context>`(): Context? defined in com.applock.lock.widget.BaseDialog
public final fun getContext(): Context defined in com.applock.lock.widget.BaseDialog
```

// error of child class in kotlin

```
Inherited platform declarations clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getContext()Landroid/content/Context;): fun `<get-context>`(): Context? defined in com.applock.lock.widget.DialogPermission fun getContext(): Context defined in com.applock.lock.widget.DialogPermission
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! if you think that the answer below helps to figure out your issue, please consider to accept it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since the method `getContext()` is final in the `Dialog` class, then you cannot override it in subclasses (`BaseDialog` in your case).

To figure this out, you can for instance define `BaseDialog` as:

```
abstract class BaseDialog(context: Context) :
    Dialog(context, R.style.PreferenceThemeOverlay) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also, there's no reason to override it. There's no reason you should want to have two different Context references in this class.